# Programmatically pre-fill Document Information Panel

Tags: infopath, content-type, dip

I have a document library, associated with a custom Content Type.
I added a link on a page, creating a new document associated to this content type (via javascript CoreInvoke).
When the document is opened, I have, in the document's associated applicationm, the DIP to fill, if needed.
My question : is it feasible to programmatically pre-fill one of this DIP fields, thanks to a textbox for example, which would be on my SharePoint page, next to the link launching the new document ?

Thank you for your wise advices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, such a scenario could only be achieved with JavaScript and query parameters fed into the URL to create a new document.

The DIP as such can be edited and customized with InfoPath, but InfoPath out-of-the-box does not have any tools or methods to look at, or interpret, query parameters that are included when the form is opened. This can be done with code, but code is not an option in a DIP form, as far as I know.

In this scenario, the parameter would need to apply to a new document's DIP. I don't think this can fly without a custom solution. You will need to set a value of a new document's column before it is created/opened in the document's application (Word? Excel? Powerpoint?)

So, can this be done? With a developer writing a new feature, probably. Without that, probably not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That confirms what I suspected :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a document template for this content type or are people just uploading any type of document? The Document Information Panel only exists for certain document and is built in to the application so I think it would be extremely difficult to do this, and may require a custom Office Add-In which wouldn't be a SharePoint solution.

To me, the question is which field, and why do you want to do this? If we understand the propblem better I think we would be in a better position to offer you solutions. I am trying to think of what the possible application for this request could be and am having difficulty imagining why you would want to do this at all.

Happy to provide feedback if you can give more detail.

Tal